# Linq sort child in query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an EF model as follows:

[image]

On this model, I can obviously use `Categories.Products` to receive a list of products.

I have a query as follows to return a list of Categories, with Products as a List to be used in an ASP.NET MVC 3 view:

```
var categories = (from a in context.Categories.Include("Products")
                  orderby a.SortOrder ascending
                  select a).ToList();
return View(categories);
```

In order to show the Products in order of their SortOrder I currently have to do:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var category in Model)
{
    <li>@category.Title
        <ul>
        @foreach (var product in category.Products.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder))
        {
            <li>@product.Description</li>
        }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

The offending line is: `@foreach (var product in category.Products.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder))` as this is handling a bit of my model in the view.

Is there a way to sort this in the query?

Comment: You could sort this in the query, but you are already handling this in exactly the right place (the view).  The model doesn't care that they are sorted (even though you have created a sort order field), and the view does.  If you implemented other "views" (consumers of the model), they might not care that the products are sorted, and you shouldn't add the sorting tax to them.  Also, you might want to allow the user to choose how they are sorted (reverse, alphabetical by description, etc), in which case you would have to re-sort in the view anyway.

Comment: In EF 4.1, can't you do `.Include( c => c.Products.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder))` using this extension method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395(VS.103).aspx ?

Comment: @Merlyn: Good point... In this case I should probably be leaving the sorting of categories to the view too, so the model just returns the 'plain' list. For my interest, how would I sort in the query?

Comment: @JD: Bala gave a method that might work, but I don't know EF well enough to tell for sure (I actually don't know it at all - only have used NHibernate).  I'm guessing you could also do it in your entity mapping, rather than when querying the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to sort this in the query?

View models of course:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller action do the necessary to fill this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var categories = 
        (from category in context.Categories
         orderby category.SortOrder ascending
         select new CategoryViewModel
         {
             Title = category.Title,
             Products = category
                 .Products
                 .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder)
                 .Select(p => new ProductViewModel
                 {
                     Description = p.Description
                 })
             }).ToList(); 
        ).ToList();
    return View(categories);
}
```

and in the `Index.cshtml` view you can get rid of ugly loops and use display templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>
<ul>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</ul>
```

and inside the display template for a category (`~/Views/Shared/CategoryViewModel.cshtml`)

```
@model CategoryViewModel
<li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)
    <ul>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Products)
    </ul>
</li>
```

and inside the display template for a product (`~/Views/Shared/ProductViewModel.cshtml`)

```
@model ProductViewModel
<li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Description)
</li>
```

As a further improvement to the controller action you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between your domain models (EF objects) and your view models which should be passed to a view.